# Cannot get content of json object element

Tags: json

```
{
    "kml": {
        "$": {
            "xmlns": "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"
        },
        "Document": [
            {
                "Folder": [
                    {
                        "Placemark": [
                            {
                                "Point": [
                                {
                                    "coordinates": [
                                        "11.0,50.0,0.0"
```

How would I get the coordinates contents. I do the following but get an error:

```
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(jsonObj.Document[0][0][0][0]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shold add the properties too, not only the array indexes:

```
jsonObj.kml.Document[0].Folder[0].Placemark[0].Point[0].coordinates[0]
```